# Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement

Tags: apex, javascript, custom-button

I am trying to query Using another class in One custom button. I need to compare one custom pick list value with another object custom field. If that matches, after click on this custom button one popup widow should appear.

```
global with sharing class PreventWarranty
{
    webService static String warranty(ID oppid)
    {
        Opportunity OppRecord = [SELECT Id, Project_Solution__c, PartnerAccountId FROM Opportunity Where Id =: oppid];
        String PartnerAccount = OppRecord.PartnerAccountId;
        string ProjectSolution = OppRecord.Project_Solution__c;
        date d = system.today().addDays(-180);
        List<Accreditation__c> AccredList = [Select Id, Solution_Type__c,Renewal_Date__c from Accreditation__c where 
                                             Account__c  = :PartnerAccount And 
                                             Renewal_Date__c < :d And
                                             Solution_Type__c = :ProjectSolution ];
        If(AccredList.size()>0)

        return 'Opportunity Number is ' + AccredList;      

    }
}
```

Here is my custom button:

[image: Code Screenshot]

I am facing this error at if condition:

> Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement.

One more error here:

[image]

Comment: You have return statement in if condition. What if this if block doesn't get execute.I think you have to add one more return for satisfying that need.`return ''` might work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
If(AccredList.size()>0)

    return 'Opportunity Number is ' + AccredList;
```

To something like:

```
If(AccredList.size()>0){

    return 'Opportunity Number is ' + AccredList.size(); 
}

return 'No Opportunity Found'; //or similar
```

The way you currently have it if the IF condition is not met then there would be no return

Comment: I think the return message inside your `if` statement should use `AccredList.size()`, not `AccredList` itself?

Comment: @Eric Thanks for your Valuable suggestion. But i still facing the error like above. Please find I updated question.

Comment: @chris  That is a different question. Your original question has been answered (I believe).  You should make a new question for that. The format here is around a specific problem not a perpetual discussion.